# .NET Application Looking for Reference Version That Doesn't Exist

Tags: .net, version, referenceerror

I have a custom reference in my project that is causing the application to fail when it cannot be found. The app is searching for version 1.30.2932... and the latest version, which I have installed, is 1.30.2928...

Is this some kind of change that occurs to v. numbers at runtime?

I've gone through the usual steps:
-checked my machine config to make sure the information there is correct
-checked web.config
-deleted temp files in (all versions) .Net Framework folders

Here is the error log, hope it helps and thanks in advance:

```
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information === 
LOG: User = IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool 
LOG: DisplayName = XYZ.Utilities, Version=1.30.2932.19647, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c3242c516e8368b7
(Fully-specified) 
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Solutions/XYZ/Branch/Portfolio_Redux/ 
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Solutions\XYZ\Branch\Portfolio_Redux\bin 
Calling assembly : XYZ.DMCS, Version=2.5.3205.18784, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=288f76032f86193b. 
=== 
LOG: This bind starts in default load context. 
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Solutions\XYZ\Branch\Portfolio_Redux\web.config 
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Aspnet.config 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config. 
LOG: Post-policy reference: XYZ.Utilities, Version=1.30.2932.19647, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c3242c516e8368b7 
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/servicerequest/a9d33737/3c0cb1cd/XYZ.Utilities.DLL. 
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/servicerequest/a9d33737/3c0cb1cd/XYZ.Utilities/XYZ.Utilities.DLL. 
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Solutions/XYZ/Branch/Portfolio_Redux/bin/XYZ.Utilities.DLL. 
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Revision Number 
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Here it is in my Web.Config:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="XYZ_UTILITIES" type="XYZ.Utilities.ConfigurationSectionHandler, XYZ.Utilities, Version=1.30.2928.18589, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c3242c516e8368b7"/>



  <runtime>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="XYZ.Utilities" publicKeyToken="c3242c516e8368b7" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.30.2928.18589" newVersion="1.30.2928.18589"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
```

*UPDATE* - Still no word on what caused this, but there was definitely something funky going on. After talking to the creators of my missing reference, there was definitely no instance with a version number of 1.30.2932... In fact, I had the newest version. A few people poured over the code, looking for something, but there was nothing to be found. I eventually just created a new class with the contents of the reference. So... in other words... if this happens to someone else, sorry for wasting your time :-/

Comment: Please show where in your code the version number is set. Maybe it's being autogenerated on each build.

Comment: Let me know if you need more than that

Comment: I meant in AssemblyInfo.cs - where the assembly is being *built*. (I'm assuming the assembly you're referring to is also one you build? You haven't made that clear.)

Comment: Sorry, it is not in my project. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the XYZ.Utilities code

Comment: Note that you haven't got a binding redirect that covers 1.30.2932. It sounds like there actually *is* a later version (2932 should be later than 2928) and you should get hold of that. Either that, or delete and readd the reference...

Comment: I've contacted the group that put the .Utilities together and the latest version is 2928, which is why I've been pulling my hair out all afternoon... I will try deleting and re-adding again. Thank you

*EDIT:* Deleting/Re-adding did not fix it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29874/discussion-between-mrcarder-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: What is the assembly version of the dll that you added as a reference? It is visible in the properties panel if you select the reference in the solution explorer.

Comment: The runtime version is 1.1... I am using .NET 3.5

Comment: The runtime version isn't the assembly version. Check the assembly version (shown just as "Version").

Comment: 1.30.2928 is the version